# htaccess rewrite {rewrite}.html --> {rewrite}

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

on an onlineshop for years all product pages ended on .html:

```
www.shop.de/cat/subcat/product.html
```

now all end without .html:

```
www.shop.de/cat/subcat/product
```

I think the shop is indexed via http and https, www.shop.de and shop.de

I need the htaccess rule to strip all urls from .html

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule (.+?).html$ /$1 [R=301,NE,NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

This is what did the trick on my server

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule (.+?).html$ /$1 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```